# MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0"

Tags: node.js, angular, msbuild

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YPXM.png)
Getting this error while trying to install an angular application.

MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".

any ideas to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you share the command you are running?

Comment: I think you should try run as admin, it works for me